# add additional logic between view and model in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a model, and it can take one of two forms:

```
{
    "x-position" : "center"
}
```

or

```
{
    "x-position" : 20
}
```

Notice how in the first example, x-position is a string, while in the second it is an integer.  These values are bound to an HTML input of type text.  I can't use input of type "number" because then it would error if it tried to interpret "center".  Therefore, I must use text.

If we look at the second example, if the user changes the value to 25, since the input html element is of type text, my model is now:

```
{
    "x-position" : "25"
}
```

The issue is the text input has now changed the value type of x-position in my model from an integer to a string (20 to "25"), which is undesirable.  This is because I'm forced to set the input type to "text", even though I want to allow both text and number, which is impossible.  I wouldn't mind accepting only string, as long as I'm able to manipulate the string somehow and convert it to number before passing it back to my model.

Is it possible for me to add an additional layer of logic between the view and model, such that if a user inputs a value "25px", I can then strip out the "px", and then parseInt("25"), then pass this value into my model as an integer...does such a thing in Angular exist?

One approach that I've tried was I set up a $watch on x-coordinate, and added some logic when the value changes via user input.  This works on a small scale for predictable data.  However, the issue with this is that my model is dynamic, constantly changing, and it could have hundreds of "x-positions" that I would have to watch.  Adding a watch to such a large amount of dynamic data seems unfeasible to me...unless I'm mistaken.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have 2 approaches here:

1. If you only need to convert to a number when you save the data, then just convert it once, when you save
2. If you really have to convert it every time the user changes the input (although I don't see a case where it would be required), then you can either define a watch, as you already did, or you can put [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) or [ng-blur](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur) on the input. (which will eventually also define a watch, but at least that way you have more control on what you pass to the function)